# Need help on setting up triggers in SQL server 2008r2

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to setup a trigger to copy any adds, updates, or deletes from one table on one server to another table on another server.  The tables have the same names.  One server is production and the other is a reports server.  Both servers are SQL Server 2008r2.  How would you go about doing this?

Comment: You would be better served setting up SQL Server Replication as apposed to trying this with triggers

Comment: Cross server triggers, is a certain death sentence for the servers involved.  Performance will go into the toilet.  As jradich1234 mentioned go Server Replication.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have setup the Replication for the table and seems to be doing what I needed. Thank you again.